# WeChat returning invalid openid error code 40003

Tags: wechat

We Chat returning below error for few openids while requesting userInfo.

Sample request:

https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/user/info?lang=en&access_token=q8RKye3NrAZrZJcdEgCZWaCW9JvNar6RHxGBsYjJbW8RcNwCyTGcs7wCVc96v5cxExICmiVRojgyTYzSO6mRimoK9PauSkbC9aQUyxALTvHSYBGf7YPQ_XceRRuGZm22QUXbAGAGKN&openid=oyH9m1hiSqxsTNnTBocpbCg5CjI

Response:
{
errcode: 40003,
errmsg: "invalid openid hint: [MRYGla0000vr21]"
}

Comment: Where did you get the openid?

Answer (score 0):

In your request the value of the openid = oyH9m1hiSqxsTNnTBocpbCg5CjI

OpenId related to a specific user of a Offical account or a Sandbox Account. First follow the account by scanning the qrcode and then go to the wechat followers get the follower openid and try the request.